# Adjoint operator of a Volterra-type integral

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the adjoint operator of $Tf(x)=\int_a^b k(x,y)f(y)dy$ for $f\in L_2[a,b]$ is $T^*f(x)=\int_a^b k(y,x)f(y)dy$.

I have done the following. Take $f,g\in L_2[a,b]$. Then,

$$ \langle Tf,g \rangle = \langle f,T^*g \rangle $$
$$ \langle \int_a^b k(.,y)f(y)dy ,g \rangle = \langle f, \int_a^b k(y,.)g(y)dy \rangle $$
For now let's assume $k$ is real-valued. Then,
$$  \langle \int_a^b \big(k(.,y)f(y) - k(y,.)g(y) \big)dy ,g-f \rangle = 0 $$
How do I proceed?

Comment: You should write it in the form of integral not inner product.

Comment: @WillCai The question doesn't specify which inner product to use. Is it the standard one: $\langle f,g \rangle =\int fg$?

Comment: Yes. $<f,g> = \int f\bar{g}.$

Comment: @WillCai But the question doesn't specify it. What if the inner-product is general!

Comment: Mostly in $L_2$, it's this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left<Tf,g\right>&=\int_{a}^{b}Tf(x)\overline{g(x)}dx\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}k(x,y)f(y)\overline{g(x)}dydx\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\overline{\int_{a}^{b}\overline{k(x,y)f(y)}g(x)dx}dy\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}f(y)\overline{\int_{a}^{b}\overline{k(x,y)}g(x)dx}dy\\
&=\left<f,\int_{a}^{b}\overline{k(x,y)}g(x)dx\right>,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
T^{\ast}g(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\overline{k(y,x)}g(y)dy:=\int_{a}^{b}k^{\ast}(x,y)g(y)dy,
\end{align*}
where $k^{\ast}(x,y)=\overline{k(y,x)}$.

Comment: The question doesn't specify which inner product to use.

Comment: Then the adjoint cannot be clearly stated.